# How to separate DOM element and display it with PHP

Tags: php, dom, element

How to separate DOM elements and display them with PHP?

I have a file `target.php`

- I want to take all `div` elements from it and store them in variable `$div` to display it later
- I want to store the rest of the elements in variable `$rest` and display it later

I am already googling but still don't have idea what to do.

here's my code:

**target.php**

```
<?php echo "something"?>

<h1>    its h1  </h1>
<h1>    its h1  </h1>

<div>   its div </div>
<div>   its div </div>
```

**index.php** (it starts here)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTMLFile('target.php');
        echo $dom->saveHTML();
        $div =$dom->getElementsByTagName('div'); //take all div element
        $rest; //take the rest of element
    ?>
        <hr />
        <div>   <?php   //echo all div element ?>  </div>

        <hr />
        <div>   <?php   //echo the rest of element?>   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I really don't know what to do

- how to get all `div` elements then display them?
- how to get the rest of the elements then display them?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried `print_r()` on `$div` variable?

Comment: Yes, please give us the value if you `echo print_r($div);`

Comment: @Coulton echo print_r($div); = DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 2 ) 1

Comment: @Daniel i don't have any error. because i don't know how to display it or filter it. in my post code i don't try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, because `$div` variable is [DOMNodeList](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). For the rest you could get each possible list of elements from your target file one by one and iterate over it. My idea is to delete divs after you echo them, but I couldn't find how to delete nodes directly from DOMDocument, so I used `<span>` to wrap all content.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument(); // Create DOMDocument object.
    $dom->loadHTMLFile('target.php'); // Load target file.
    $div =$dom->getElementsByTagName('div'); // Take all div elements.
    $neutralNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0); // Get element which holds all important nodes for us.
    ?>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <?php
        $divsToRemove = array(); // Create array to store div nodes.
        foreach($div as $el) { // Iterate over divs DOMNodeList.
            echo '<div class="' . $el->getAttribute('class') . '" style="' . $el->getAttribute('style') . '">'  . $el->nodeValue, PHP_EOL . '</div>'; // Echo out div.
            $divsToRemove[] = $el; // Store current div in array.
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <?php
        foreach($divsToRemove as $divToRemove) // Loop over divs to remove them.
            $neutralNode->removeChild($divToRemove); // Remove target divs from node which holds all.
        echo $dom->saveHTML(); // Echo rest of HTML.
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**target.php**

```
<span>
    <?php echo "something"?>

    <h1>    its h1  </h1>
    <h1>    its h1  </h1>

    <div style="color: red;">   its div </div>
    <div style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">   its div </div>
</span>
```

Comment: i need the div not the node value. this code will break if i change the div in target.php into <div style="background-color: red">   its div </div>

Answer (score 1):

you are loading your html file through the file system that way the php inside will never get executed. And dom can't build a nice object with php code still inside the node. You have to use:

```
$htmlfile = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/target.php');
$dom->loadHTMLFile($htmlfile);
```

And the dom returns a object you can loop through with foreach.

**Explanation domdocument**

This mabay confusing but you can not use print_r or var_dump on domdocument objects. So sorry for that inconvenience.

But you can loop through them see my example:

**target.php**

```
<?php echo "<h1>dsasdasd</h1>"?>

<h1>header</h1>
<h1>also header</h1>

<div>contentindicshit blabla</div>
<div>I am a hobbit (no I am not!)</div>
<div>lalalalal</div>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    $htmlfile = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/shit/node.php');
    $dom->loadHTML($htmlfile);

    $div = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('div');

    echo $div->item(1)->nodeValue; // just by singe selecting (litle bit strange syntax near item(1)->nodeValue)

    echo '<br><br>';

    //by looping
    foreach($div as $item){
        echo "$item->nodeValue <br>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: can u post the full code.apologize because i still don't know what to do

Comment: Well in that case. I shall see what I can explain but you need to learn the fundamentals of php.

Comment: thanks.. yes i will use file_get_contents. i know exactly what you mean now